# youtube video blocks buttons on mobile browser

Tags: button, video, youtube

could you help me with the following case:
I have a youtube video on my website.

```
<iframe width="400" height="225" src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/jKIfjiIjd?
rel=0&  color=white&iv_load_policy=3&theme=light" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Beneath and above this video I have some form elements like

```
 <button class = "button" id = "video" type = "submit" onClick = "javascript: somefunction();" >some value</button>
```

The video is in its own div, the buttons and form elements are in their own divs.

The buttons work perfectly on the desktop browsers, however on the mobile browsers those buttons, that are beneath the video are impossible to click (top buttons are working fine) I figured out that if I remove the video from the page, all the buttons start working. The buttons also work for the first few seconds before the video is fully loaded. So, it looks, like the video is invisibly overlapping the area 100-150px beneath it and makes impossible for mobile browser users to click on any element. (ps Ive tried to use z-index of 1000 - no effect)

Please, help.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: additional info, it looks like the video invisibly keeps the original hight of the youtube video (480) and blocks every element 480px beneath the top of the video

Comment: additional info, the buttons work when the video is playing (or finished playing), like if before playing it has the height of 480px (even though I see the determined 250px) and after starting turned to the 250px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the exact same issue with the YouTube iFrame. I've been testing all day. Here is where I'm at:

The problem is the  element that is inside the YouTube iFrame.

```
<video class="video-stream html5-main-video" controls="true" 
x-webkit-airplay="allow" data-youtube-id="..............."></video>
```

If you 'display:none' that, or change it to 'top:0'. It fixes the problem.

However, since it's inside the iFrame, I dont know how to change it.

Comment: Google thread on this.
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=4569

Answer (score 0):

To add to this discussion attached is a link to a fiddle of the issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/krismeister/KynXG/5/

```
//<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<h1>The youtube iframe has a video tag which on iPad blocks touches on elements beneath  the iframe.<br><em>tap below the video and you will see no color change.</em></h1>
<div id="vid-placeholder"></div>
<div id="bg"></div>
```